# Pull some data, based on a date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need to pull some data, based on a date.

QUESTION;

what is the value in column D, based on a date for example 'TODAY' or 2/4/2022

I ideally want to populate this detail onto another tab, where it will update daily.

not very easy to explain, but hope someone caught me drift.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].  Also add small representative data sample and the expected result as text rather than as image. If you case is complex you might also add a link to spreadsheet but all the essential details should be included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!A2:A = today())`

...or:

`=filter(Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!A2:A = datevalue("2022-04-02"))`

Comment: That's great, thanks for the advice!

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)